# Insert information into SQL database from Text File

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code to take a large text file that uses commas as delimiters, and input it into a database.

I am getting an error with the fget and feof parts of the code. The file is uploading successfully.

It says "feof(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource..." and "fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource..."

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$allowedExts = "txt";
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
  else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}



$tableArray = array();
$handle = @fopen("/uploads/". $_FILES["file"]["name"], "r");

require ('connect.php');

while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.
    list($fname,$lname,$snumber,$gender,$a , $b, $year,$DOB, $phone,$c,$email,$d,$e,$R,$r,$w)=explode(",",$buffer);
    $sql_statement = "INSERT INTO students  VALUES ($snumber , $fname , $lname , $gender , $year , $email, $DOB , $phone , 1)";

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LOAD DATA INFILE query for this

You can find the documentation here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

And to open a file use:

```
$handle = fopen("<file location>","r");
```